# Nuances of Cantor Intersection Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve the following problem in Kolmogorov's real analysis textbook.

> Give an example of a complete metric space $R$ and a nested sequence $\{A_n\}$ of closed subsets of $R$ such that $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \emptyset$. Reconcile this example with [Cantor's intersection theorem.]

Cantor's intersection theorem states that for a complete metric space $R$ and a sequence $\{A_n\}$ of closed and nested subsets whose diameter $0$ as $n \to \infty$, the infinite intersection of the $A_n$ is nonempty.

Based on the statement of this theorem, it seems that the only assumption I do not have is the fact that the diameter of the $A_n$ approaches $0$. It would seem, therefore, that this is how we get an example that we can reconcile with Cantor's intersection theorem, but I am still struggling to think of a good example. If $R$ didn't have to be complete, I think it would certainly be possible to find such a set. But I recall from the proof of Cantor's intersection theorem that the diameter approaching $0$ is needed to establish that the sequence of elements generated from the $A_n$ is Cauchy. I'm not sure if this lends itself to a proof via constructing a sequence of $A_n$ whose elements do not become infinitely close to each other.

Any help on this result would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take $A_n=[n,+\infty)$ with the usual metric on the real line.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just to make sure I understand your suggestion correctly: I can certainly see that $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_n \supset \cdots $ in this case (though I still need to prove for myself that these sets are closed). As for their infinite intersection, I suppose the argument is that if we supposed for a contradiction that there were some $x \in \bigcap\limits_{n \to \infty} A_n$, then I can just take some $m > x$ and consider the set $A_m = [m, \infty)$, in which case $x \not \in A_m$, a contradiction. Thus the diameter doesn't approach $0$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes exactly..this intervals are nested and closed unbounded intervals..if you want to prove the closedness use the sequential charaxterization of a closed set in a metric space...and their diametes are always infinite..so that;s the difference with Cantor's theorem.

Comment: If I understand this correctly then: we take a sequence $(x_m)$ entirely contained in $[n, \infty)$. Because $x_m \geq n$, it can't converge to an $m < n$ (otherwise, we just set $\epsilon = \frac{m+x}{2}$ and get a contradiction). So the only remaining possibility is some limit greater than or equal to $n$. Is that on the right track? Thank you again for all of the help.

Comment: Yes..if $x_m \geq n$ for every $m$ then $\lim_mx_n \geq n$ (if the sequence has a limit  off course

Comment: How does the diameter not converge to 0.Can you suggest a better visualisation?

Comment: @Krishan the diameter of each set is $+\infty$...these sets have an infinite ''length''